# Errors running junit test with spring-cloud-task annotation

Tags: spring, junit, spring-cloud-task

I have strange errors running junit tests in my spring-cloud-task based app and have not been able to find a cause for this.

This is a fragment of my test class followed by the error stack trace. I've notice that removing the @EnableTask annotation there's no problems running test.

Does anyone has any suggestion?

Thanx

```
package eu.wheesbee.cloud.stream.app.discoverit.fundedproject.task.config;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.EnableTask;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;


@DirtiesContext
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = FundedProjectImporterBatchTest.FundedProjectImporterTestConfiguration.class, 
                        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
public abstract class FundedProjectImporterBatchTest {

  @Autowired
  protected ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

  public static class TestBatchConfigurationSuccess extends FundedProjectImporterBatchTest {

    @Test
    public void testBatchConfigurationSuccess() throws Exception {
      System.out.println("-----------------------------------------   Ciao!!!!!!!!");
    }
  }


  @EnableTask
  @SpringBootApplication
  public static class FundedProjectImporterTestConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @PostConstruct
     protected void initialize() {
      ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
      populator.addScript(resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:db/schema-all.sql"));
      populator.addScript(resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:db/data.sql"));
      populator.setContinueOnError(false);

      DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(populator, dataSource);
    }
  }

}
```

Here the stacktrace :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ApplicationContext loaded for [[MergedContextConfiguration@69b794e2 testClass = FundedProjectImporterBatchTest.TestBatchConfigurationSuccess, locations = '{}', classes = '{class eu.wheesbee.cloud.stream.app.discoverit.fundedproject.task.config.FundedProjectImporterBatchTest$FundedProjectImporterTestConfiguration, class eu.wheesbee.cloud.stream.app.discoverit.fundedproject.task.config.FundedProjectImporterBatchTest$FundedProjectImporterTestConfiguration}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextCustomizer@23faf8f2, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@64729b1e, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@6895a785, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@ea1a8d5], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]]] is not active. Ensure that the context has not been closed programmatically.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:70) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:87) ~[spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117) ~[spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230) ~[spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:539) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:761) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:461) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:207) [.cp/:na]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: use standard @SpringBootTest with @TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.cloud.task.closecontext_enable=false"} as described here

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/docs/1.2.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/#_writing_your_test

TNX

Comment: FYI, that will be changed in upcoming versions (You won't need that anymore).